# Cloud ML Engine and Scikit-Learn: 'LatentDirichletAllocation' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, google-cloud-ml

I'm implementing simple Scikit-Learn `Pipeline` to perform `LatentDirichletAllocation` in Google Cloud ML Engine. Goal is to predict topics from new data. Here is the code for generating pipeline:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(shuffle=True, random_state=1,
                             remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
train, test = train_test_split(dataset.data[:2000])

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('CountVectorizer', CountVectorizer(
        max_df          = 0.95,
        min_df          = 2,
        stop_words      = 'english')),
    ('LatentDirichletAllocation', LatentDirichletAllocation(
        n_components    = 10,
        learning_method ='online'))
])

pipeline.fit(train)
```

Now (if I have understood correctly) to predict topics for test data I can run:

```
pipeline.transform(test)
```

However, when uploading pipeline to Google Cloud Storage and trying to use it to produce local predictions with Google Cloud ML Engine I get error that says `LatentDirichletAllocation` has no attribute `predict`.

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict \
    --model-dir=$MODEL_DIR \
    --json-instances $INPUT_FILE \
    --framework SCIKIT_LEARN
...
"Exception during sklearn prediction: " + str(e)) cloud.ml.prediction.prediction_utils.PredictionError: Failed to run the provided model: Exception during sklearn prediction: 'LatentDirichletAllocation' object has no attribute 'predict' (Error code: 2)
```

Lack of predict-method can be seen also from docs, so I guess this isn't the way to go with this.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html

Now the question is: What is the way to go? How to use `LatentDirichletAllocation` (or similar) in Scikit-Learn Pipelines with Google Cloud ML Engine?

Comment: Interesting case... Truth is, [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer) doesn't have a `predict` method either (it has a `transform` one), but it doesn't produce an arror...

Comment: @desertnaut from `Pipeline` documentation I understood that `predict` is applied only for last estimator. Thats why `CountVectorizer` doesn't  produce errors. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.predict

Comment: (disclaimer: I'm not a python expert ..)  I spelunked the source code and the `BaseEstimator` does *not* in fact have a `predict()` method (nor does `LatentDirichletAllocation` itself).  But the `mixins` for `BaseEstimator` do mention the `predict()` method. So it is a bit challenging to see how/where `predict()` were implemented . So is the error returned by Google appEngine valid or not?

Comment: @pipo. As per my answer below, this is not currently supported, but we have some possible workarounds coming soon. Are you willing to discuss your use case over email? If so, please email cloudml-feedback@ and reference this post.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the last estimator of a pipeline must implement the `predict` method.

Comment: Is there any update on the workarounds? I'm also interested.

Comment: We have a solution we're currently alpha testing. We'd love if you'd give it a try and provide us feedback. Contact us at cloudml-feedback@google.com for info on how to get started.